# How to config dns of a virtual machine in Azure to point to another domain

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine

I have an application that is installed on a virtual machine in `Azure`. It is accessible with the public ip and the dns name offered by Azure.

I have a domain name with ssl in namecheap. I want to point the dns name from Azure to it or another provider.

To illustrate even more:

My app is accessible to the outside world using: `x.x.x.x/app/login`

or with: `mydnsname.azure.com/app/login`

What I want is: `anotherdomain.com/app/login`

[image: azure to namecheap]

I don't want to change my records inside namecheap, i.e. changing `CNAME` record to point to my dns and `A` record to the public ip of my vm.

I know this method but in my situation it doesn't work.

[image: namecheap to azure]

Comment: Never use `1.1.1.1` as an IP address in examples... It is a live IP that supports a service used by a lot of people nowadays.

Comment: Its not really clear what you're asking - if you want to point your domain name / SSL cert to the VM, then you need to change your records inside namecheap.

Comment: I want to do the opposite. Change Azure VM dns records to point to namecheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain owner has control over what mmappings can be made.

Microsoft owns the Address space of the VM, and the *.azure.com namespace. When you provision a VM you are allowed a name in their namespace `mydnsname.azure.com`

if you own `example.com` you can then map `something.example.com` in the same way that Microsoft do. However since you are not the owner of `Azure.com` you have no ability to map anything other than what the owners of that domain have given you. You have no ability whatsoever to map anything against the `azure.com` namespace, with the sole exception of the name that you are provided for your VM.

Comment: I'll recap what you've said: You can map example.com to mydnsname.azure.com (I already know this) but not quite the opposite (this is what I am asking) since Azure doesn't allow me to edit my subdomain records inside the vm. Could you confirm that?

Comment: You don't have a sub domain record, you have a host record. A subdomain would need to have name server records etc. You can change things locally on the server, but that won't change anything on the public internet

Comment: I see. So to summarize, no you can't map to another domain name from Azure Vm. You are limited with xxx.xxx.xxx.azure.com or trying the first map, e.g. namecheap -> azure -> internet

Comment: Unfortunately, that is your only option